# Can not set state on fetch react native

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

Hello I tried to set the state on fetch call like this:

```
    getCats() {
        fetch(GLOBALS.API + '/specials.php?action=getCats&key=' + GLOBALS.KEY)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState = ({
                dataSource: "test"
            });
Alert.alert("test");

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.toString());
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCats();
        console.log(this.state.dataSource);
    }
```

but the line:

```
console.log(this.state.dataSource);
```

return me undefined
and I get an alert of "test"

what the problem?

tnx a lot

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: i am glad that it works for you. could you upvote as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You Can Make Use of callbacks.***

*Below is the code example*

```
getCats(successCallBack, failureCallback) {
    fetch(GLOBALS.API + '/specials.php?action=getCats&key=' + GLOBALS.KEY)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                        response.status);
                    failureCallback();
                }
                // Examine the text in the response
                response.json().then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    successCallBack(data);
                });
            }
        )
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            failureCallback();
        });
}
```

*Below is the code for success and failure call backs*

```
successCallBack(data) {
     console.log(data)
}

failureCallback() {
    alert("failure");
}
```

*Below is the code to bind success and failure callbacks.*

```
getCats(this.successCallBack.bind(this), this.failureCallback.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is asynchronous so it will return immediately, before the code in the then clauses are run. Therefore, setState will not have run before the console logging.

Comment: so how i create listview after the fetch with the data on the fetch?

Comment: When changing the state, the component will automatically re-render. I.e., if the render method properly depends on the state, a state change is all that is needed to automatically have the UI updated upon a state change. So one method would be to have an initially empty array as a state variable, loop over that variable in the render method (rendering your listview), and populate the state variable with values from the http request, causing the re-render with the updated values.